# Insert pattern before match on the same line containing pathname

Tags: regex, sed

How can I comment out lines containing full pathnames using `sed`?

I know `sed` can use almost any other delimiter, but I'm not sure how I would change it in this case.

Test file:

```
cat test
/usr/share/test1.sh
/usr/share/test2.sh
```

Expected output:

```
sed '/\/usr\/share/s/^/#/' test
#/usr/share/test1.sh
#/usr/share/test2.sh
```

Actual output:

```
sed '|/usr/share|s|^|#|' test
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `|'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '\|/usr/share|s|^|#|' test
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. Darn those tricky escape characters!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
$ cat input
This is a line
/usr/share/test1.sh
/usr/share/test2.sh
/usr/bin/test.sh

$ sed 's@^\(/usr/share/\)@#\1@' input
This is a line
#/usr/share/test1.sh
#/usr/share/test2.sh
/usr/bin/test.sh
```

BTW, your example sort of works, her's an updated version:

```
$ sed '\|\/usr\/share|{s|^|#|}' input
This is a line
#/usr/share/test1.sh
#/usr/share/test2.sh
/usr/bin/test.sh
```

If you want to use different delimiters for a regular expression in the address, you need to start the address with a backslash.